# How to find the minimum element in a Map and return a tuple (key,minimum element)?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml, minimum

I have these types :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
```

I've written those modules to create my Map :

```
module MyMap =
  struct
  type t = node
  let compare (a1,b1) (a2,b2) =
    if a1 > a2 then 1
     else if a1 < a2 then -1
     else if b1 > b2 then 1
       else if b1 < b2 then -1

       else 0
  end

module DistMap = Map.Make(MyMap)
```

I've tried to write functions that used `iter` but my attempts to formulate my ideas in a correct syntax were unsuccessful.

My goal would be able to have a function that takes a Map as argument and return a tuple of the minimum element and its key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking for the minimum key and its corresponding element, that's easy: use `DistMap.min_binding_opt`, or `DistMap.min_binding` if you're fine with raising an exception on an empty map.

If you're asking for the minimum element and its corresponding key, you will want to use a fold. Luckily, the `DistMap` module returned by `Map.Make` exposes a `fold` function, so you don't have to do extra allocation by, say, calling `to_seq` and doing a fold on the result. In addition, because the type of elements in a map is not constrained by the functor application (i.e., you can create a map with any element type), you will need the client to supply a comparison function for the element type.

`DistMap.fold` has type `(key -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b -> 'b`, so we'll have to instantiate `'b` in such a way as to keep track of both the key and the min element; in other words, we'll instantiate `'a` as the element type of the map (let’s call it `t`), and `'b` as `(key * t) option` (where `key = position = float * float`).

Here's what the code might look like:

```ml
let min_element_and_its_key map ~compare_element =
  let take_min key element key_and_min_element =
    match key_and_min_element with
    | None -> Some (key, element)
    | Some (key_for_min_element, min_element) ->
      if compare_element element min_element < 0
      then Some (key, element)
      else Some (key_for_min_element, min_element)
  in
  DistMap.fold take_min map None
```

`min_element_and_its_key` will return `None` on an empty map.

Example client code (which you can run in an ocaml repl) might look like:

```ml
let map = DistMap.(empty |> add (3., 3.) "a" |> add (4., 4.) "b") in
min_element_and_its_key map ~compare_element:String.compare;;

(* Output: *)
- : (node * string) option = Some ((3., 3.), "a")
```

In general, anytime that you want to traverse all keys/elements in a data structure and accumulate a value, a `fold` is the way to go. `iter` will sort of work, but you'll have to accumulate the value in mutable state instead of accumulating it directly as the return value of the function you're folding with.

Comment: Is it normal if I have a syntax error for the test ? The error is at the ```in```.

Comment: The test I gave you is an expression, not a top-level declaration. To include it as a declaration in your file, you can write: `let () = (* and then the same expression as before *)`.